# Handling 4-block oriented matrix product and inversion in Maxima

Tags: matrix, symbolic-math, maxima

I am concerned in finding symbolic solutions and expansion to matrix products and inversions. Actually, it is something I would like to define by myself. I will explain myself.

I want to create a "mathematical" object that i will call `B4MAT` which represents a square matrix whose elements are 4 square half-sized matrices. So I want to define the product between two `B4MAT` giving me back another `B4MAT` whose components are calculated by applying product rules, but among matrices, not scalars.

Furthermore, and this is a very important point, consider [Blockwise Inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion) of a matrix. I want to define inversion of a `B4MAT` as an operation returning me another `B4MAT` whose elements are calculated using the blockwise inversion algorithm in the link.

How to achieve this in Maxima?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

For the first half of your question, you just need to change `matrix_element_mult` to non-commutative multiplication and then use a matrix whose elements are the blocks you want. For example:

```
Maxima branch_5_27_base_248_ge261c5e http://maxima.sourceforge.net
using Lisp SBCL 1.0.57.0.debian
Distributed under the GNU Public License. See the file COPYING.
Dedicated to the memory of William Schelter.
The function bug_report() provides bug reporting information.
(%i1) A: matrix([1,2],[3,4])$ B: matrix([2,1],[3,4])$

(%i3) matrix([A,B], [B,A]);
*** output flushed ***
(%i4) C: matrix([A,B], [B,A]);
                            [ [ 1  2 ]  [ 2  1 ] ]
                            [ [      ]  [      ] ]
                            [ [ 3  4 ]  [ 3  4 ] ]
(%o4)                       [                    ]
                            [ [ 2  1 ]  [ 1  2 ] ]
                            [ [      ]  [      ] ]
                            [ [ 3  4 ]  [ 3  4 ] ]
(%i5) C . C;
                          [ [ 5   5  ]  [ 4   4  ] ]
                          [ [        ]  [        ] ]
                          [ [ 18  32 ]  [ 18  32 ] ]
(%o5)                     [                        ]
                          [ [ 4   4  ]  [ 5   5  ] ]
                          [ [        ]  [        ] ]
                          [ [ 18  32 ]  [ 18  32 ] ]
(%i6) matrix_element_mult: ".";
(%o6)                                  .
(%i7) C . C;
                          [ [ 14  16 ]  [ 13  17 ] ]
                          [ [        ]  [        ] ]
                          [ [ 33  41 ]  [ 33  41 ] ]
(%o7)                     [                        ]
                          [ [ 13  17 ]  [ 14  16 ] ]
                          [ [        ]  [        ] ]
                          [ [ 33  41 ]  [ 33  41 ] ]
```

I think you have to code up the inversion formula yourself though (don't forget you can get at the blocks with expressions like "C[1][2]" (for the top right corner) etc.